# Why is orbitControls not working on mobile device

Tags: javascript, three.js, orbitcontrols

I am running THREE.js and am attempting to build a 360 video viewer that works on mobile devices, however orbitControls isn't working at all on my phone, it works perfectly fine when on PC

I've tried to research and find someone with this issue but no one seems to answer it. I've seen things that say that it should work but nothing I do works.

https://jsfiddle.net/wmorris01/3ctv9hdL/2/

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
controls.enabled = true
controls.touches.ONE = THREE.TOUCH.PAN
controls.touches.TWO = THREE.TOUCH.DOLLY_ROTATE
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. 

Do you have specific reason to use r128?

2.
You don't need "THREE"

```
controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
```

set like this

```
controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement);
```

3. 

Set this tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

And your question about Live Server, well, I don't know. I use bundler (Vite), and you should try either.

Comment: I did this but it's giving me this error: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'ONE')

Comment: Did you initialize the controls before using touches?
controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
  controls.touches.ONE = THREE.TOUCH.PAN;
  controls.touches.TWO = THREE.TOUCH.DOLLY_ROTATE; (and basically could you provide some code?)

Comment: Yeah i did. Ive added the fiddle to the main comment

Comment: I changed it to the first one you showed and that error no longer shows up however I still isnt working on mobile, or in the mobile part of developer tools. Could it be a problem with using VSC Live Server?

Comment: Check those options in my last edit.